# Connect iTunesConnect and AppStoreConnect tags

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, tag-synonym-process

Anyone involved with iOS or macOS apps knows that [the iTunes Connect website has recently been renamed to App Store Connect](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=06042018). There has been a [itunesconnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itunesconnect) tag for quite some time and recently someone created the [appstoreconnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appstoreconnect) tag. It only has 4 questions at the moment and all of them also have the [itunesconnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itunesconnect) tag.

I think it would be better to rename the old [itunesconnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itunesconnect) tag to [appstoreconnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appstoreconnect) and make [itunesconnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itunesconnect) a synonym. No need to have both of these tags. So we need a simple retag, tag rename, and tag synonym.

Comment: Seems like you just need to merge/synonymize. Is that what you mean by a "rename"?

Comment: @Catija I'm not sure really. The end result should be that the many existing uses of itunesconnect should now appear as appstoreconnect (which retagging all of those questions) and any attempt to use itunesconnect will result in appstoreconnect through the synonym.

Comment: Yeah, if you merge, you don't have to retag anything (manually). We don't "rename" tags as far as I'm aware. Merging two tags replaces all instances of the secondary tag with the primary tag and synonymizing them makes it so that future uses of the secondary tag will be automatically retagged with the primary tag.

Comment: Currently, the [appstoreconnect] tag is a suggested synonym for the [itunesconnect] tag. It should be the other way round, since the new name is App Store Connect, so it makes less sense to have [itunesconnect] as the primary tag.